# Joomla - Unable to include CSS in dashboard plugin page for deactivated plugin

Tags: joomla

I am creating a custom system plugin for Joomla 3.9. In the dashboard I need to include CSS for the same. When the plugin is active/Enabled, I am able to do the same but when the plugin is inactive, CSS file is not getting included.

Comment: If the plugin is injecting the CSS file into the head, the plugin must be enabled. Plugins are not executed if they're disabled

Comment: But I am trying to inject CSS in the dashboard (in the plugin setting page) not in the front-end.

Comment: Oh I see. You mean the settings page for that specific plugin?

Comment: yes..can I do that? Do you have any solution for same?